# Xamarin forms scrollview and layoutTo not working

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin-studio, xamarin.forms

I'm creating an app using Xamarin Studio on a Mac. 
The problem I'm facing is that a scrollview only works in the place where it was originally placed at.

I mean, I've a layout that slides to the right and left based on user input (I've two menus, one on the right and the other on the left, you get it). However, if the user doesn't open any menu the scrollview scrolls correctly, if the user does slide, it doesn't work anymore!

Here's how I'm handling the layout sliding with Xamarin.Forms:

```
    public void toggle(){
        Rectangle oldBounds = (Parent as RelativeLayout).Bounds;
        oldBounds.X = -oldBounds.Width/ 3 * (_toggled?0:1);
        (Parent as RelativeLayout).LayoutTo (oldBounds, 600, (_toggled?Easing.CubicOut:Easing.SpringOut));

        _toggled = !_toggled;
    }
```

Any function I might need to call? For example, forceLayout or something similar? I've tried this one and it doesn't work either!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you isolate this issue into a small app to better illustrate the issue perhaps?  If so I will take a closer look if you can send it across on email - my contact details are on my Profile.

Comment: Is the issue in iOS or Android?, When I ran the example on iOS it looked ok, unless I'm missing something obvious?

Comment: No, it doesn't work in both. :/ Thanks for your help Pete!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i managed to solve this! Check the [github repository](https://github.com/fcouceiro/xamarin-forms-scroll-view-troubleshoot) I created with an example. I included a comment on top of DetailView.cs explaining how I did it (hacky way of course! ;) ).

Basically I lay them side by side in a layout that fills all main page and than I use LayoutTo to change that layout Width so that the side menus are hidden.

Than, when you show them aka slide them in, they'll work as expected!

So, thats it, Xamarin.Forms dual panel sliding without any custom rendering!

Thanks for your help!

Comment: This repository has been deleted, unfortunately.

Comment: In the end I dropped xamarin forms and started an android and an ios project. If your app is more than simple listviews and simple navigation you'll find it much more difficult to create the desired app in forms rather than creating it separately.

Answer (score 0):

It may be worth considering to use the **Xamarin.Forms** **MasterDetailPage** as this has *slide-out* functionality inbuilt and works well, although I've experienced mixed results using an emulator in **v1.2.2x**, but works well on a device.

So instead of inheriting from **Content Page** you could inherit from **MasterDetailPage** and things will be easier to implement, rather than attempting to write your own.

The only downside to the current **MasterDetailPage** implementation in **Xamarin.Forms** is that the **slide-out** only happens from the *left-hand side*.  This is unfortunately **fixed**.  You couldn't even specify the fly-out to occur from the *right side* and also there is **no support** for **dual** slide-out areas, from the left and right sides (tested on version **1.2.3x**).  Chances are they will introduce possibly the slide-out direction and possibly dual-slide out areas in a later release but you would need to contact **Xamarin** on this as to whether its possible and the timeframe for such a feature.

In your current implementation there appears to be something getting in the way of the **ScrollView** that is preventing it from doing its normal action, and its not obvious what this is due to how your doing things on your page.

There are implementations of *dual-sliders* on **Android**, but I haven't looked for **iOS**, let alone **WindowsPhone**.

If you do manage to find them, you could perhaps write a custom renderer to use existing implementations to ease trying to re-create one yourself?

Comment: I'm currently waiting for Xamarin Team to provide some feedback. However if we manage to get this to work it would just be perfect for Xamarin to introduce dual panel slide-out areas within Xamarin.Forms ;)